# Unity 2D, Vector2 + Vector2 Not Outputting the result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector2

I'm adding two Vector2's together and the result is simply the first Vector2 even though the second Vector2 has a value, its a small value but still a clear value which should be added to the first one. Does anyone know what could output this?

Code that has the debug logs and the addition of Vector2s:

```
   public virtual WeaponState UpdateState()
    {
        Vector3 translate = new Vector2(Mouse.current.delta.x.ReadValue(), Mouse.current.delta.y.ReadValue()) * sensitivity;
        if ((Vector2)translate == Vector2.zero)
            return this;

        Debug.Log("WeaponPos: " + weapon.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Translation: " + translate);
        Vector2 newMousePos = new Vector2(weapon.transform.position.x + translate.x, weapon.transform.position.y + translate.y);
        Debug.Log("WeaponPos + Translation: " + newMousePos + ". WeaponPos: " + weapon.transform.position);
        Vector2 pivotPoint = weapon.GetPivot();
        float distanceWhenTraveled = UtilityF.Distance2D(newMousePos, pivotPoint);
        return Execute(pivotPoint, newMousePos, distanceWhenTraveled);
    }
```

An example of an output:

```
WeaponPos: (-9.02, 2.41, 0.00)
Translation: (0.00, -0.01, 0.00)

WeaponPos + Translation: (-9.02, 2.41). WeaponPos: (-9.02, 2.41, 0.00)
```

Why is the result of "WeaponPos + Translation" not (-9.02, 2.40) here instead?

[This is the place where the debug logs are written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn5j1.png)

[This is the output of the debug logs captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh7dV.png)

Comment: Use `v.ToString("f7")` to show the value of a vector. The actual math may be 2.414 - 0.005 = 2.409

Comment: Thank you so much, that explains it all! The normal ToString() shows rounded decimals and therefor not the exact results, thank you!!